# How to disable automatic page_view logging in Firebase analytics

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm using the official [Firebase JS SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk) in a Vue-based SPA. To get more useful analytics through Firebase's `firebase.analytics()` Google Analytics integration, I would like to *disable automatic reporting of `page_view` events.*

I'm aware that, under the hood, Firebase Analytics uses Google's gtag.js for reporting to Google Analytics and I know that I can [configure gtag](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/app-web/disable-page-view) to not send that event automatically like so:

```
gtag('config', 'MEASUREMENT_ID', {
  'send_page_view': false
});
```

My problem is that I can't seem to find a way to set that kind of configuration value through `firebase.analytics()`. I've tried `analytics.setUserProperties({ send_page_view: false })`, but that doesn't seem to work as the page_view event is still reported to Google.

Is there any way to set this configuration value in Firebase analytics or is there another way to disable automatic page-view reporting here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently searching for this same solution.
I am using firebase analytics in a react spa app. For me, the solution proposed by @Draven does not seem to work.

Using the GA Debug chrome extension, I can see `Processing GTAG command: ["config", "G-3MVDF7WX31", {send_page_view: false}]` being called, but shortly after I also see `Sending event "page_view" to undefined` being called. After that, `Processing GTAG command: ["config", "G-3MVDF7WX31", {send_page_view: false}]` is called again. Using the [Google Analytics DebugView](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) I can still see the page view event being logged.

*UPDATE*

Looking through the Firebase JS SDK, there does not seem to be a way to disable the default page_view, which occurs during the call to `firebase.analytics()`. However I came up with a workaround which, after light testing, seems to work.
Place the following BEFORE you call `firebase.analytics()`:

```
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }

gtag('set', { 'send_page_view': false });
</script>
```

See github issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/3988

Answer (score 2):

You can use Firebase with existing gtag.js tagging. Based on this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=web#firebase-gtag), you'll need to call firebase.analytics() first before sending events using gtag() and the data will be associated to Firebase.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js"></script>

...

firebase.analytics();

...

gtag('config', 'MEASUREMENT_ID', {
  'send_page_view': false
});
```